# gradle-Android Studio NDK Build trouble Error:Execution failed for task ':app:cleanNative'

Tags: java, android-studio, gradle, android-ndk

I'm rather new to android studio and I'm in Android Studio NDK Build trouble.
I'm working in windows 10.

**The IDE shows following Error Message while building the project**

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:cleanNative'.
>   Process 'command 'D:\android-ndk-r10e\ndk-build.cmd'' finished with non-zero exit value -1073741819

**build.gradle(app module)**

```
    android {
    signingConfigs {
    }
    ...
        ndk {
            moduleName "behagcoder"
            cFlags "-DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFPM_ARM -ffast-math -O3"   // Define some macros
            ldLibs "android", "log"       // Link with these libraries!
            stl "stlport_shared"
        }
        multiDexEnabled true

    }

    packagingOptions {
        ...
    }

    sourceSets.main {
        jni.srcDirs = [] // This prevents the auto generation of Android.mk
        jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/libs'
    }
    task buildNative(type: Exec, description: 'Compile JNI source via NDK') {
        if (Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS)) {
            def ndkDir = "D:\\android-ndk-r10e"
            commandLine "$ndkDir\\ndk-build.cmd",
                    '-C', file('src\\main\\jni').absolutePath,
                    '-j', Runtime.runtime.availableProcessors(),
                    'all',
                    'NDK_DEBUG=1'
        } else {
            def ndkDir = "/home/Downloads/android-ndk-r10d"
            commandLine "$ndkDir/ndk-build",
                    '-C', file('src/main/jni').absolutePath,
                    '-j', Runtime.runtime.availableProcessors(),
                    'all',
                    'NDK_DEBUG=1'
        }
    }
    task cleanNative(type: Exec, description: 'Clean JNI object files') {
        if (Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS)) {
            def ndkDir = "D:\\android-ndk-r10e"
            commandLine "$ndkDir\\ndk-build.cmd",
                    '-C', file('src\\main\\jni').absolutePath,
                    'clean'
        } else {
            def ndkDir = "/home/arobil/Downloads/android-ndk-r10d"
            commandLine "$ndkDir/ndk-build",
                    '-C', file('src/main/jni').absolutePath,
                    'clean'
        }
    }
    clean.dependsOn 'cleanNative'
    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn buildNative
    }
   .....
}
```

Comment: For windows you are using android-ndk-r10e and for other os you are using  android-ndk-r10d .  Please use the same version of ndk for each platfrom .